# mysqld vs mysql socket files

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble connecting via phpmyadmin to mysql. I can bring up the login page but when I try logging in I get these 4 errors:

```
 #2002 - Connection refused &mdash; The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

So I have been trying to find what is wrong. I did notice that my `mysql.cnf` is empty except for these two lines:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

I have no idea what ! means in this respect but I assume that it means to use those two files instead.

I go into `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and I see

```
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

Is there anything wrong with this config of the local server socket? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: You need to change your `bind-address` to the actual IP address of the server, and restart `mysqld`.

Comment: MySQL can run only on the localhost so no need to change this with exception if you want to connect from external server. Please paste the output off service mysql status